# Nginx. Rewriting all requests except one path

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx

This is my rewriting rules in config file.

```
location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*)(?:\?(.*))?$  /mis/page/home last;
        rewrite ^/login(\?.*)?$     /account/page/login$1 last;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?_url=$1 last;
    }
```

I want to rewrite `/login` to `/account/page/login$1` and all others request to `/mis/page/home` and then all requests should be rewrited to index.php.

But that with the configuration above, I got `500 Internal Error` from the server and error message in `error.log` is :

```
rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/mis/page/home"
```

How can I implement my requirement?

Thank you.

Comment: You need a better idea of what *all others* means, because currently, `/mis/page/home` is included in *all others*. What is the purpose of rewriting twice? Do you mean to make `/mis/page/home` a redirect?

Comment: I want to make all requests to be rewritten to "/index.php?_url=" and I need all requests render a same page except "/login".

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to serve either `/account/page/login$1` or `/mis/page/home` to your `/index.php?_url=`?! Because that's what the last rewrite does. It is a catch-all.

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/login(\?.*)?$     /account/page/login$1 last;
    rewrite !^/login  /mis/page/home last;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?_url=$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be looking for literal `?` in the regular expressions of your `rewrite` statements, but `nginx` uses a *normalised* URI which is stripped of the query string. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

If the default action is to use `/index.php` with a `_url=/mis/page/home` parameter, it can be constructed directly in the `try_files` statement.

To keep things partitioned, use a separate location block for the `/login` URI.

Maybe I have oversimplified your requirement, but this is what I mean:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=/mis/page/home;
}
location = /login {
    rewrite ^ /index.php?_url=/account/page/login last;
}
```